# Which function is like the cubic function rotated 90 degrees?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I need something like the cubic function $y=x^3$ rotated 90 degrees. Which function is that?

Answer (score 6):

$y=-\root3\of x$

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: But x cannot be negative using this function. Are there other ways?

Comment: @Linksku: yes it can.

Comment: I'm not very good at functions. According to the following link, if x is negative, then it curves downwards: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D-x%5E%281%2F3%29
Am I missing something?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+-sgn%28x%29*abs%28x%29%5E%281%2F3%29). (Wolframalpha only seems to know the complex variant of the cube root.)